# Tortoise SVN update and commit doesn't work

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, svn-update, svncommit

I am having issues with Tortoise SVN lately. I am unable to update and commit anything.

```
Tortoise SVN version: 1.6.16 Build 21511 - 64 bit
OS: Windows 8 server
```

We use VisualSVN Server for the repo.
[image]

Whenever I try to update, I see the following screen where it doesn't update anything actually and it just stays like this for hours. 
Similarly, when I try to commit anything, I get the error message below
[image]

It happens only on my computer. Other developers are running the same OS, same `TortoiseSVN` version and they can update and commit to the `repository`, so I think there is nothing wrong with the repository itself.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the same version of Tortoise but that doesn't work.

I also tried to update to revision -> select "Head" option and then select "Fully Recursive" in the Update Depth dropdown.

I don't prefer to change to the newest version of `TortoiseSVN` as I would like to stay on the same version of Tortoise that other developers are using here.

Comment: Are you sure you have Write access to the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using `http://` as the Subversion repository?

Can others commit changes to the repository? If so, it's probably an issue with your user ID. Are you setting a username and password when committing changes in Subversion? Does your user have commit access to the Subversion repository?

On the server side, users can have read permission that allows them to checkout, read-write permission that allows them to check files in and make changes, or have no access at all. You may need to verify your user permissions.

If no one can check files in, it could be a permission issue with the files in the repository itself. However, if you're using VisualSVN, and you created the repositories in VisualSVN, tht shouldn't be an issue. Just make sure whatever process is running the server has read/write access to the physical files in the repository itself.

Another issue could be a pre-commit hook that prohibits making commits due to various issues. However, if that's the case, it usually reports back the *exit code* of the pre-commit hook. I don't see that in your error message, so I don't think that's the issue. Are you the Subversion administrator? If not, you'll have to talk to the SVN administrator to see what's going on with your account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after hours of troubleshooting I figured out the issue was not with SVN or my account, it was with one of the files. 
Website has an integration with weather underground and all the code and weatherunderground data is checked in to SVN as well. There was some temp file by weather underground which was causing the issue and didn't let me use TortoiseSVN. 
Thank you for taking a look in to this issue though.