# SVN Update not working in Tortoise

Tags: svn, version-control

I am having problems with the SVN update menu ooption in tortoise SVN i.e. a window appears saying completed but nothing appears to of happened i.e. the working copy has not reverted back to the previous committed version.  The commit option works ok.

I have read questions like this: [Tortoise SVN update and commit doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436259/tortoise-svn-update-and-commit-doesnt-work), but I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: @bahrep, agreed.  +1 for link and "accept" for best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use ["Update to Revision"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html#tsvn-cli-updaterev) to update your working copy to specific revision,
- If you want to revert changes in your repository, check ["Undoing Changes"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html#tsvn-qs-revert) section.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to 'update' to the most recent version and get rid of any pending local changes, you might want to try doing an SVN Revert instead of Update. It shows up in the same context menu as 'Update' in Tortoise SVN.